# A puzzle about the error "redefinition of struct"

Tags: c, struct, case-sensitive, redefinition

My IDE is [C-free 5.0](http://www.programarts.com/cfree_en/index.htm), the compiler is [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

I have two files:'list.h','list.c'

list.h:

```
typedef int elementType; 
#ifndef _LIST_H
#define _LIST_H

struct node;

typedef struct node* ptrToNode;
typedef ptrToNode list;
typedef ptrToNode position;

list makeEmpty(list l);
#endif
```

list.c:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    elementType element;
    position next;
};

list makeEmpty(list l){
if(l == NULL){
    //delete list
}
l = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if(l == NULL){
    printf("fail to malloc memory");
    exit(-1);
}
l->next = NULL;
return l;
}
```

I try to compile this files then I got an error

```
"list.c:5: redefinition of 'struct node'"
```

Then I replace all the "**node**" with "**Node**", the amazing things happened! The compiling is OK! I really can't undersand this. Is this may related to C library?

Comment: You can't mix cases in C, this is not Perl! Pick, it's either all `node` or all `Node`. There's no magic...

Comment: sorry for my eidition which causes your misundersand, I have corrected my code above

Comment: Is this absolutely all the code you're compiling? My MinGW compiles it just fine.

Comment: That shouldn't matter - the IDE doesn't (usually) compile, it's the compiler's part. But I've run it using the command line, no IDE in my case. What's your answer regarding having any other code involved?

Comment: this is absolutely all the code i am compiling.I try again and get the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The thing about the struct and typedef can be quite confusing at least it is for me.
As struct creates a type already when you use a C++ aware compiler you have to reformulate your statements. Push the definition into the header instead of the forward declaration.
It is this one "typedef struct node* ptrToNode;" which creates the double declaration if I am not mistaken. There are quite some good articles here discussing the topic about typedef's and structs. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think it is all **compiler dependency**. It works fine with visual studio. You may try it in following way if you don't want to rename "node" to "Node" (I expect it to work until MinGW has its own node defined somewhare):

list.h:

```
typedef int elementType; 
#ifndef _LIST_H
#define _LIST_H


typedef struct node{
    elementType element;
    struct node* next;
}*ptrToNode;


//typedef struct node* ptrToNode;
typedef ptrToNode list;
typedef ptrToNode position;

list makeEmpty(list l);
#endif
```

and ur list .c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "poly.h"
#include <stdlib.h>


list makeEmpty(list l){
if(l == NULL){
    //delete list
}
l = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if(l == NULL){
    printf("fail to malloc memory");
    exit(-1);
}
l->next = NULL;
return l;
}
```